# How do I update a date field with just the date portion of a time-stamp field?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to update a datestamp field with data from a timestamp field in the task table. the timestamp column is datatype "DATETIME" while the datestamp field is datatype "DATE"
the changes are based on an assigned_user_id field, and I'd like to narrow it down to rows with non-matching dates (some already are correct).
I know I can just run this:

```
UPDATE task 
   SET datestamp = timestamp 
 WHERE assigned_user_id = useridstring 
   AND datestamp != timestamp
```

but the problem is even when the dates DO match, the query thinks they don't because the timestamp contains a time which the datestamp field does not... how do I limit the check to only read the date portion of the timestamp field?

Comment: @Sam M: yepyep! I found it here: [link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-datetime/)

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
UPDATE task SET datestamp=timestamp WHERE assigned_user_id=useridstring AND datestamp!=DATE(timestamp);
```